# FT2232H Asynchronous FIFO mode

Tags: ftdi, fifo

Has anyone seen an FT2232H port not go into the mode set into the EEPROM? I've got a device that is programmed to be in asynchronous FIFO mode on port A, but functions as though it's still in UART mode. Curious if any else has ever seen something like that, and if there's a solution for it.

Comment: How did you determine that it is still in UART mode? Did you monitor the pins activities or do you assume that because the device is still visible as a VCP?

Comment: I checked the function of the pins. I actually got it out of that by going through a procedure to flash a clean template on it. Apparently the part will drop into UART mode if the string descriptors get messed up. Getting it back isn't a matter of cleaning up the descriptors, but rather cleaning out the EEPROM by erasing it, and building a new template from scratch with as few modifications as necessary to get it into 245 mode. One of the clues is TXE# will just float in tri-state. VCP is a valid driver for 245 FIFO mode, and it can deliver a heavy stream of data.

Comment: gz for solving it. Maybe you should post it as answer and accept it then.

Comment: I'm not convinced I answered it, though. I know it got messed up, and I know I fixed it. But what exactly fixed it? I posted the question to see if anyone had seen this before, and whether there is a deterministic fix aside from trashing the EEPROM, and starting over.